# Detecting IE8 reliably using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have written a web app that requires IE version 8 (or higher presumably). If I run IE8 on a clean windows install on a VM it reports 'MSIE 8.0' as a user agent when queried with navigator.userAgent in javascript. But on a colleagues windows 7 machine his IE reports version 8 in the Help|About window, but the user agent string is 'MSIE 7.0'.

I figure that somewhere on his machine there is a setting that's telling IE to spoof the previous version, some kind of compatibility setting I presume, but for the life of me I can't find it. I'm not setting up quirksmode or IE7 compatibility mode from my end.

Comment: do you really need to check for the browser version? or can you just use feature detection? because i [expletive] hate browser detection.

Comment: @geowa4 - I am a f***ing fan of the asterisk form of censorship. :)

Comment: @ChaosPandion yeah well [expletive] you! :-P

Comment: @geowa4: Actually it's the better CSS standards support afforded by IE8 that I'm looking for; I don't know how to feature detect for that specifically. Of course I could feature detect for something IE8 specific anyway. Either way the question remains, why is the user agent reporting a previous version?

Comment: or rather, what is my web app doing that is causing the user agent to misreport, because if it is misreporting, that might mean it's being put into compatibility mode by the web app, which is precisely the behaviour I'm not looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var is_ie8_or_newer = false;
</script>
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
is_ie8_or_newer = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i'm not sure if that works for a browser running in compatibility mode. have you tested it?

Comment: @Rushyo: I think that's just what you want: Opera presenting itself as IE is still Opera and acts like Opera.

Comment: Depends. To override a user's intent is typically a bad thing(tm). Then again, the user is an idiot for relying on spoofing.

Comment: @Rushyo: But Opera only put spoofing in Opera to let users use sites that rely on (bad) browser sniffing, so they can use sites that otherwise would be inaccessible (that's also why this is a per-site setting).

Comment: @Quentin: I'm going to flag this as the correct answer although I made some slight modifiations. I used `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge">`. It turns out that prevents IE 8 from ever falling back on compatibility mode, which it turns out was the problem. The default setting for IE is to force all intranet sites into compatibility mode.

Comment: not good. javascript should be ran from .js file, whereas this code meant for html only.

Comment: I'd reverse this and assume that the user is not using IE8 and use the conditional comment to to detect IE8 and update the the var. This is because not all browser support the comments and the market share is dropping fast - best to target the current/future trend by default.

Comment: @BWRic — Err… that is what this code is doing. That is why the variable is set to **false** and the only changed if a suitable version of IE is detected.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I see that now. It's because I can here looking for a way to detect IE8 or lower so my head was working the opposite way when I read it. Sorry!

Comment: This won't work on IE10+ since IE10 stopped supporting conditional comments

Answer (score 7):

The user agent is not a sensible or reliable way of determining the browser version.
Why don't you look for the presence of the feature you require by making it IE8 only and use that?
That is a much more reliable method.

Comment: I've heard this a million times and it's true when you're dealing with a particular feature. But when it's a quirk unrelated to a specific feature that you still have to deal with, it's helpful to have strategies that don't involve detecting something entirely unrelated to what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

The most entertaining trick I've seen — without having any idea of how efficient it is — is to leverage the IE conditional comment feature *dynamically*.  To do that, your code takes a hidden `<div>` or a `<div>` in a document fragment, or whatever, and inserts into it some HTML surrounded by a conditional comment coded to check for a specific browser version:

```
var dummy = document.getElementById('dummy');
dummy.innerHTML = '<!' + '--[if IE 8]>x<![endif]-->';
var isIE8 = dummy.innerHTML === 'x';
```

IE8 can show a little button next to the URL box that switches the browser between IE7 mode and IE8 mode. You can open up the "Developer Tools" and that'll tell you what the current setting is.

Comment: That's very much like http://gist.github.com/527683, http://gist.github.com/542301 and http://gist.github.com/548648

Answer (score 2):

Could you use conditional comments?

```
<script>
  var is_ie8 = false;
</script>
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <script>
    is_ie8 = true;
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.modernizr.com/

It should detect such issues. Alternatively, I'm not sure but IE 8 might switch its User-Agent tag in 'Compatibility Mode'.

Comment: UA sniffing is even worse than version detection in JS - see Chrome's UA for a taste of the insanity: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.9 Safari/533.2` (some braindead scripts are looking for "Gecko" in the script, because that's what Firefox has; and don't get me started on the initial "Mozilla")

Comment: Modernizr detects *features*, not bugs, incompatibility or browser versions

Comment: @Yi Jiang: ah ok, I must have misunderstood. I was reacting to the part about User-agent.

Comment: @Piskvor And I was responding to the original poster of this answer... Your comment didn't showed up when I was typing the comment.... clarified.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Which is often (usually?) the legitimate intent of people asking questions about user agent sniffing.

@Piskvor: I wasn't advocating anything, just responding to the question. He wanted to see what was weird with his scenario - I suspect it might have been that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can figure out how to get my version of IE8 to say that it is IE7 is to enable Compatibility View. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out his browser was set to display all 'intranet sites' in compatibility mode. Also, yes, compatibility mode changes the user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

Found this sweet function on [GIT (in the comments)](https://gist.github.com/padolsey/527683):

```
function getIEVersion() 
{    
    var v = 3, div = document.createElement('div'), a = div.all || [];
    while (div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><br><![endif]-->', a[0]); 
    return v > 4 ? v : !v;    
};
```